# I want to integrate IronSource ad network with my react native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, github, ads

I have found a framework for integrating IronSource ad network with my react native project [here](https://github.com/wowmaking/react-native-iron-source).

I have a searched a lot in internet and have already tried opening an issue in the repository but no luck.

I did as it said in the readme file like so:

First installing the dependency

`npm install @wowmaking/react-native-iron-source --save`

Then linking the dependency

`react-native link @wowmaking/react-native-iron-source`

And finally importing the dependency

`import { IronSource } from '@wowmaking/react-native-iron-source';`

But as soon as I try to run my application I get this error:

> native module cant be null

I don't know if I'm doing it right or not please help!

I'm using react native 0.60.5

Comment: Do you mean Android?

Comment: Did you add a repo in your app/build.gradle file ?

Comment: react native supports both iOS & Android

Comment: it says if I add ```react-native link @wowmaking/react-native-iron-source``` all will be linked so?

Comment: Not sure if it will be added. Would you like to check?

Comment: but when I install it the folder is not created in node modules

Comment: Did the installation complete correctly?

Comment: do you have whatsapp or instagram to chat there

Comment: I'm really stuck I need help

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm contributor of `@wowmaking/react-native-iron-source`.
Readme was updated for RN 60 last month. You dont need to link it anymore for RN 60.

1. `npm install @wowmaking/react-native-iron-source --save`
2. Add a repo to your android/app/build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Existing repos here
        // ...

        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/ironsource-mobile/android-sdk" }
    }
}
```

You are ready to run your app.

3. Add mediation networks which you need. Follow official docs. 
   https://github.com/wowmaking/react-native-iron-source#mediation-setup

Answer (score 0):

Re-build your project via:

```sh
react-native run-android
```